# gcc error: Can't create precompiled header

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, precompiled-headers

I have some useful typedefs on a header file called utypes.h. I have decided to use make and haven't found a way to compile it since then.

When I execute `gcc -Wall -c utypes.h` to generate the .o object of utypes I get the following error:

```
"utypes.h:1 fatal error: can't create precomiled header types.h.gch: Permission Denied (EACESS)
Compilation terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: please, don't compile headers, just do an include of them.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549648/compilation-fatal-error-header-file-g) is related, but not quite identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have write access to the directory where you are trying to put types.h.gch, or you have a pre-existing read-only copy. On Linux you can use strace to get the details.

Comment: I am not using linux. What do you suggest me to do? Don't use make?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make your environment clear, and hope that someone wanders along who has seen this before. Is it cygwin or Ming?

Answer (score 0):

just compile your stdc++.h in cmd with administrator rights. Run CMD as Administrator and then go to path of stdc++.h and then compile